# Ubuntu 18.04 logon screen touchpad buttons not working

Tags: touchpad, 18.04, gdm

The buttons on my touchpad do not work on logon screen (both tap and physical buttons). The mouse portion of the touchpad works just fine. After I login (using keyboard) everything works without issue.

Additionally I noticed yesterday that if I log out the keyboard also does not work making it impossible to login again without shutting down first.

The mouse portion of the touchpad works in both cases though.

Can anyone offer help on this issue?

Also note that this issue first started when I upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10

I did some looking around and found someone recommending to set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-to-click to true with gsettings but it was already set to true when I checked.

gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-to-click

true

Comment: Maybe this will help, go to `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` then add `pci=nomsi`  and delete `acpi=0` from this line  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash  acpi=0"`-------->`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash 
 pci=nomsi"  `    ... I always have problem like this! and i fix it by above solution!

Comment: no luck :) I tested it out by editing the line in grub